# HttpClient ObjectContent JSON: format with root class name in json object?

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

I generate a C# class for a json source using json2csharp.com. My json is:

```
{
  "email_verified": true,
  "user_id": "gg2323",
  "app_metadata": {
    "tc_app_user": {
      "user_guid": "c0fb150f6er344df98ea3a06114e1e4a",
      "cto_admin_a_user_id": "551294d4f6cfb46e65a5aq71",
      "lang": "EN",
      "country": "USA",
      "disabled": false
  }
```

and my resulting C# is:

```
public class TcAppUser
{
    public string user_guid { get; set; }
    public string cto_admin_a_user_id { get; set; }
    public string lang { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public bool disabled { get; set; }
}

public class AppMetadata
{
    public TcAppUser tc_app_user { get; set; }
    public int logins_count { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool email_verified { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public AppMetadata app_metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Using the .NET HttpClient GET, I can read into this C# structure from the JSON API quite nicely. Going the other way (POST, PATCH) poses a problem: my app_metadata property name is dropped in the generated JSON output when I use a common approach like:

```
    //Would be nice: var contentIn = new ObjectContent<string>(RootObjectInstance.app_metadata, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());  
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObjectInstance.app_metadata);         
HttpResponseMessage response = await hclient.PatchAsync("api/users/" + user_id, new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

The resulting JSON is now:

```
{
    "tc_app_user": {
      "lang": "en-en",
      "country": "GER",
      "disabled": false
    }
}
```

My quick hack is to use the following additional wrapper to dynamically repackage the app_metadata property so it has the same format going out that it had coming in. The rest remains the same as above:

```
dynamic wireFormatFix = new ExpandoObject();
                wireFormatFix.app_metadata = usr.app_metadata;
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wireFormatFix);
```

Now my JSON output corresponds to the JSON input. **My question**: what is best-practice  to achieve symmetric json input and output here without a pesky format fix?

EDIT: If I try to PATCH the entire structure (RootObjectInstance instead of RootObjecInstance.app_metadata) I get:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Payload validation error: 'Additional properties not allowed: 'user_id'."
}
```

So, I must either send the app_metadata subset/property of the C# RootObject, properly packaged, or I must selectively delete fields from the RootObject to meet the API's requirements.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you serializing `RootObjectInstance.app_metadata`? Why not simply `RootObjectInstance`?

Comment: The remote API requires a PATCH using only permitted "patch" portions of the JSON structure once the initial remote structure is created via POST. If I send the entire root object, I get errors from the remote service.

Comment: What error do you get? And how is that different from what you're doing?

Comment: There error: 400 unallowed fields are present. The remote service only permits a PATCH of app_metadata, not the entire RootObject (which it delivers when I GET).

Comment: OK, I'll edit. My RootObject has more than this app_metadata.

Comment: Edit your `RootObject` and post the error message.

Comment: Done. See also edit at bottom.

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/apiv2#!/users/patch_users_by_id

Comment: Perhaps you need to different objects for what you're trying to do? It seems that they dont allow the `user_id` property.

Comment: See my edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `app_metadata` tag is being removed from your JSON because you're simply not serializing it. This:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObjectInstance.app_metadata);
```

Will serialize everything that is **inside** `app_metadata`.

If you serialized the entire object graph, you wouldn't need to patch anything:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(RootObjectInstance);
```

As a side note, you should follow [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use `JsonProperty` to help you with that.

**Edit:**

Ok, after your edit i see the actual problem. You're calling an API by `user_id` in your query string, and you also have a `user_id` property inside your object. This seems like you need two different objects for the job.

You have a couple of possibilities:

1. Create an object hierarchy:

   ```
   public class BaseObject
   {
       [JsonProperty(email_verified)]
       public bool EmailVerified { get; set; }
       [JsonProperty(app_metadata)]
       public AppMetadata AppMetadata { get; set; }
   }

   public class ExtendedObject : BaseObject
   {
      [JsonProperty(user_id)]
      public string UserId { get; set; }
   }
   ```

And then use the base type to serialize the data:

```
var baseObj = new BaseObject(); // Fill the object properties.
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intermidiateObj);
HttpResponseMessage response = await hclient.PatchAsync("api/users/" + 
                                                        user_id, 
                                                        new StringContent(json,
                                                        Encoding.UTF8,
                                                        "application/json"));
```

2. Use an anonymous object which includes only properties you actually need:

   ```
   var intermidiateObj = new { app_metadata = usr.app_metadata };
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(intermidiateObj);
   HttpResponseMessage response = await hclient.PatchAsync("api/users/" + 
                                                       user_id, 
                                                       new StringContent(json,
                                                       Encoding.UTF8,
                                                       "application/json"));
   ```

Comment: Sorry, that does not answer the question. I understand the behavior all to well :-) I still need to include the property name (app_metadata) into the output without a hack/workaround if possible. It may not be possible...

Comment: Thanks. Naming: I agree. Names are being dicteted by external sources in this case and I'm not going to mix and match :-)

Comment: Well, maybe it is not a hack :-) So I had the best approach all along. I assumed there is perhaps a better approach. Maybe not. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer does not solve the problem. The hack is what I use to workaround and add-back the app_metadata namespace (wrapper). It is not a PATCH if I serialize the entire graph. That would be a POST or PUT and I'd be redefining the user in that case, not patching it.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, I guess I can accept this as the answer: that there is no better way :-) Essentially, you are doing the same thing I am...